# Parameter count mismatch. on setDataSource

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am trying the following and my report contains no parameters also Iam using .Net Objects

```
 Dim data = GetDataConnection()
 Dim ds = (From th In data.TranHeads Where th.THCSCode = "YYY001"
              Select th).ToList

 Dim crySalesTran As ReportDocument = New IBS_DAL.rep_SalesTransaction

 crySalesTran.SetDataSource(ds.AsEnumerable)

 CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crySalesTran
```

for some reason when it reaches setdatasource

TargetParameterCountException 
 Parameter count mismatch.

Comment: Have you stepped into the `SetDataSource` call to see if you find out more information about the error?

Comment: @KarlAnderson what method do you use to bind reports as I can't understand why this is failing

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer although not sure why this works and the other option doesn't

```
Dim da = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT THSysRef, THCSCode FROM TranHead Where THCSCode = "YYY001" ", data.Connection)
Dim dtTH = New DataTable
da.Fill(dtTH)

Dim crySalesTran As ReportDocument = New IBS_DAL.rep_SalesTransaction
crySalesTran.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(dtTH)

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crySalesTran
```